# send form data to php page with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form like this,

```
<form id="frm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="inp_txt" id="inp_txt"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sbtn" value="send" id="sbtn">
</form>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
 $(function(){

  var request ;

   $('form#frm').submit(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   if(request){
       request.abort();
   }

   var $form = $(this);
   var $inputs = $form.find('inputs');
   var serailize = $form.serialize();

   console.log(serailize);

   $inputs.prop('disabled',true);

   request = $.ajax({
      url:'form.php',
      type:'post',
       data:serailize
   });

   request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
       console.log('oky');

       $.ajax({
           url: "form.php",
           type: "get",
           success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
           },
           error:function(){
              console.log('bad');
           }
       });
   });

   request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       console.error(
           "The following error occurred: "+
               textStatus, errorThrown
       );
   });

   request.always(function(){
       $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
   })
 })
})
```

and my php code in `form.php`

```
<?php
  $name  = $_POST['inp_txt'];

  echo(json_encode(array(data=>$name)));
?>
```

but I have big problem ,
In this section of my javascript code :

```
$.ajax({
           url: "form.php",
           type: "get",
           success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
           },
           error:function(){
              console.log('bad');
           }
```

I get the message from `post.php` in `console.log(data)`

```
Undefined index:inp_txt in htdocs\phpajax\form.php
```

Please help me solve this problem, 
thanks

Comment: Your second ajax request doesn't send any data. Why are you making two request in the first place?

Comment: In addition to that, your ajax is sending a GET the second time whilst your PHP is expecting a POST.

Comment: @MohsenNiyazdel.H post.php?? form.php rite... try putting if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') and if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')

Answer (score 0):

set data type to `json` in ajax's settings object:

```
$.ajax({
       dataType :'json',
       url: "form.php",
       type: "get",
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
       },
       error:function(e){
          console.log(e);
       }
   });
});
```